# Resize desktop icons Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, files, icons, .desktop, desktop-icons

How can I resize the desktop icons?

[image]

They are too big. I tried to use the zoom out option in nautilus, but it didn't work

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Following the above hints with the gsettings command I edited the command line to:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.icon-view default-zoom-level standard
```

And my desktop icons popped back to the correct size.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is a limitation of `nautilus` with the minimum size being `48px` hard-coded within their software. The setting that control this is:

```
gsettings range org.gnome.nautilus.icon-view default-zoom-level
```

You can see by running this command it's already set to small, so it can't get smaller:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.nautilus.icon-view default-zoom-level
```

In order to get smaller icons you would have to actually recompile the code, at which point you basically won't be getting updates for `nautilus` anymore:

- [Discussion and directions to compile these changes manually](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250266/rhel-7-gnome-shell-decrease-desktop-icon-size)

It's also worth mentioning that if customization is something you desire the Kubuntu flavor of Ubuntu based on KDE may interest you.

Comment: +1 to KDE's customization. I don't use icons on the desktop, but KDE flavors offer six icon sizes for desktop icons with a simple GUI to make the changes.

Comment: An afterthought: you could ask a question about resizing icons on Kubuntu's desktop and provide the answer as well!

Answer (score 0):

From Olek at

https://ubuntu-mate.community/c/support

The command to change a single icon size is :

gio set /home/your_user/Desktop/your_file.xlsx metadata::icon-scale 1

scale can be changed for the one you wish.

1 is the smallest size icon.

To make it for all objects on your desktop you can create a simple bash script that will do it :

```
#!/bin/bash

folder=$(echo ~)/Desktop/*

for x in $folder; do
echo "$x"
gio set "$x" metadata::icon-scale 3
done
killall caja
```

You have to kill caja in order to reload the new config.